# SP2019 Mix Shared/Dedicated Minroles

Tags: sharepoint, installation, sharepoint-2019

Setting up a SP2019 environment. Documentation I found online mentions doing either Shared Minroles for all the servers or dedicated for all.  My question is, can you mix them or is it one or the other?  I don't see why you couldn't but before I do, I wanted to see if anyone has gone down this road before.

Example

```
Server 1: Front-End Minrole
Server 2: Front-End with Distributed Cache
Server 3: App w/Search Minrole 
etc...
```

Thanks!

Have not tried the configuration yet.  Researched it online but can't find a definitive answer.